# Format the output - python

Tags: python

I have this code here

```
import subprocess
from time import strftime       # Load just the strftime Module from Time

f = open('check_'+strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.log', 'w')
for server in open('check.txt'):
    f.write(server.strip() + "\n")
    subprocess.Popen(['plink', server.strip(), 'df','-k'],stdout=f)
```

What I would like to have is the output so it shows:

> Server Name
>
> Output
>
> Server Name
>
> Output

Currently it shows:

> server name
>
> server name
>
> output
>
> output

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - if your intention is to run different commands in remote servers, take a look at [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/).

By default subprocess.Popen runs in the background, and your command is probably much slower than the other things in your loop (like printing the server names). Try this to force it to wait for each process:

```
import subprocess
from time import strftime       # Load just the strftime Module from Time

f = open('check_'+strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.log', 'w')
for server in open('check.txt'):
    f.write(server.strip() + "\n")
    p = subprocess.Popen(['plink', server.strip(), 'df','-k'],stdout=f)
    p.wait()
    f.flush()
```

If you *intend* to make the process run in parallel, I'd just write each server log to a different file. Then concatenate the result if needed.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for that, it solved it.  I changed the f.flush() and p.wait() round as it was printing the server after the output.